# How to add slide animation on multiple buttons in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've 3 buttons and by default the first one is selected and has orange background the rest 2 has gray background. when a user clicks on 2nd button the `background` should slide from 1st button the 2nd and when user clicks on the 3rd one background should slide from 2nd to 3rd. and opposite when the user is on 3rd button and clicks on 1st. background color and rest styles should move from 3rd to 1st.I am using tailwind for this app.
Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Store from "../../assets/store.jpg";

const TopOptions = ({ showOption, setShowOption }) => {
  const [clickedButton, setClickedButton] = useState(0);
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

  const buttons = ["DELIVERY", "TAKEAWAY", "DINE IN"];
  

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
          <p className="text-xxs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
          <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
            <img src={Store} alt="store" className='object-contain' />
            <select className="pl-2">
              <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div className=" bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
            {buttons.map((btn, index) => (

              <button
                className={
                  "w-full py-3 font-bold text-sm " +
                  (clickedButton === index
                    ? "bg-orange text-white rounded-md shadow-xl"
                    : "text-gray-600")
                }
                onClick={() => {
                  setClickedButton(index);
                  setIsShowing(!isShowing);
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                {btn}
              </button>

            ))}

          </div>

      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TopOptions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work for you.

The basic idea is to use a separate, absolute-positioned element as the bg and change its left offset depending on which element is selected:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Store from "../../assets/store.jpg";


const TopOptions = ({ showOption, setShowOption }) => {
    const [clickedButton, setClickedButton] = useState(0);
    const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
  
    const buttons = ["DELIVERY", "TAKEAWAY", "DINE IN"];
    const leftOffsets = ["left-0", "left-1/3", "left-2/3"];
  
    return (
      <>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
            <p className="text-xxs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
              <img src={"Store"} alt="store" className="object-contain" />
              <select className="pl-2">
                <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
  
          <div className="relative bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
            <div
              className={
                "w-1/3 top-0 absolute h-full bg-blue-500 rounded-md shadow-xl duration-500 transition-all " +
                leftOffsets[clickedButton]
              }
            />
  
            {buttons.map((btn, index) => (
              <button
                className={
                  "w-full py-3 font-bold text-sm relative z-1 " +
                  (clickedButton === index ? "text-white" : "text-gray-600")
                }
                onClick={() => {
                  setClickedButton(index);
                  setIsShowing(!isShowing);
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                {btn}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
  
  export default TopOptions;
```